# ¿Como graficar pixeles?

Tags: java, java-swing

Soy nuevo en java encontré este código para graficar pixeles, pero solo los grafica cuando se da clic en donde se desea, yo quiero dar las coordenadas y que lo haga automáticamente ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

```
public class Circunferencia {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Pintar Pixel");
    f.setSize(600, 400);//tamaño de la ventana
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//centrado
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//salir al cerrar
    f.setVisible(true);//hacer visible la ventana
     
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setSize(600, 400);//tamaño del panel
    f.add(p);//agrega a la ventana el panel creado
     
    //Evento de click al panel
    p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseClicked(e); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
           //capturamos del evento e la posicion x,y donde dimos click
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        //pintamos el pixel en el panel
        p.getGraphics().drawLine(x, y, x, y);
        }  
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No sólo ese código no funciona como vos querés. Sino que además los dibujos se van a perder si pasás una ventana por encima de la que tiene el `JPanel`. O si movés esa venta a fuera de la pantalla arrastrando con el mouse y luego la volvés a poner visible. Porque la interfaz gráfica necesita que los componentes se dibujen nuevamente cuando las cosas que te indiqué ocurren. Y el código que mostrás sólo dibuja cuando hacés el click.
Lo correcto es que implementes tu propia versión de `JPanel` y que escribas el método `paint()` de forma que sirva a lo que querés.

```
@Value
static class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;
}

@Builder
static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    @Singular
    private List<Point> pixels = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        pixels.forEach(point -> g.drawLine(point.getX(), point.getY(), point.getX(), point.getY()));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Pintar Pixel");
    f.setSize(600, 400);//tamaño de la ventana
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//centrado
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//salir al cerrar
    f.setVisible(true);//hacer visible la ventana

    MyPanel p = MyPanel.builder()
            .pixel(new Point(10, 30))
            .pixel(new Point(100, 30))
            .pixel(new Point(15, 1))
            .pixel(new Point(500, 100))
            .pixel(new Point(50, 250))
            .build();
    p.setSize(600, 400);//tamaño del panel
    f.add(p);//agrega a la ventana el panel creado
}
```

En este código definí una clase `Point` para representar el punto 2D. Y un subtipo de `JPanel` para heredar todo el comportamiento y sólo sobreescribí el método `paint()` para poder dibujar la lista de puntos. Ese método se va a llamar siempre que sea necesario (de eso se encargar la UI). Acá simplemente recorro la lista y dibujo los puntos.
Usé Lombok para ahorrarme escribir getters, constructores y builders.